# Change button background image on hover/click using a template

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got an application with tons and tons of buttons which I want to make a bit more fancy with hover/click effects. I was hoping one could use a styling template for this so I wouldn't have to write the triggers for each and every button, but I am kind of stuck in this phase.

I think you get the general idea of what I am trying to accomplish here with this code snippet:

```
<Button BorderBrush="#00000000" Foreground="#00000000" Height="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" IsEnabled="True" Name="btnMinimizeWindow" Width="21" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,0,4,2" BorderThickness="0" Focusable="False" Style="{StaticResource ModernButton}">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyApp;component/Images/btnMinimize.png" />
    </Button.Background>
    <Button.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Default" >
            <Image Source="/MyApp;component/Images/btnMinimize.png" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Hover">
            <Image Source="/MyApp;component/Images/btnMinimizeHover.png" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Active">
            <Image Source="/MyApp;component/Images/btnMinimizeActive.png" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

and the template file:

```
<Style x:Key="ModernButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter Name="Content" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                    </Trigger>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">

                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How do I go about this problem? Is it even possible to do it this way or do I have to clutter my code with millions of triggers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) for the background images for states *Normal*, *MouseOver* and *Pressed* (and maybe more). You would use these attached properties for the `Source`property of separate Image controls in a control template and modify e.g. the Image's Opacity when the [VisualState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstate.aspx) changes.

An example style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="mouseOverBackgroundImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="pressedBackgroundImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Image Name="normalBackgroundImage" Source="{TemplateBinding local:BackgroundImages.NormalBackgroundImage}"/>
                    <Image Name="mouseOverBackgroundImage" Source="{TemplateBinding local:BackgroundImages.MouseOverBackgroundImage}" Opacity="0"/>
                    <Image Name="pressedBackgroundImage" Source="{TemplateBinding local:BackgroundImages.PressedBackgroundImage}" Opacity="0"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

used in a Button with the attached properties set:

```
<Button local:BackgroundImages.NormalBackgroundImage="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Tulips.jpg"
        local:BackgroundImages.MouseOverBackgroundImage="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"
        local:BackgroundImages.PressedBackgroundImage="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg"
        Content="Hello"/>
```

And finally the definition of those attached properties:

```
public static class BackgroundImages
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalBackgroundImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("NormalBackgroundImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(BackgroundImages));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverBackgroundImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseOverBackgroundImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(BackgroundImages));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedBackgroundImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PressedBackgroundImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(BackgroundImages));

    public static ImageSource GetNormalBackgroundImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(NormalBackgroundImageProperty);
    }

    public static void SetNormalBackgroundImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(NormalBackgroundImageProperty, value);
    }

    public static ImageSource GetMouseOverBackgroundImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(MouseOverBackgroundImageProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMouseOverBackgroundImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MouseOverBackgroundImageProperty, value);
    }

    public static ImageSource GetPressedBackgroundImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(PressedBackgroundImageProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPressedBackgroundImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(PressedBackgroundImageProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Elegant solution, works like a charm. Attached properties is from now on my best friend :-)