# Simple WPF Button Control Template with variable images?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, controls, controltemplate

I am still new to WPF (writing my first app with it), but basically I am wanting (or think I want) to create a control of somekind that has 3 images (idle, hover, onClick) but that I can change the images. So now I have:

```
                <Rectangle Height="29" Width="35" Margin="0,2,0,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                       Name="BTN_OpenDeviceSettings" ToolTip="Open Device Settings"
                       Fill="{DynamicResource device_grid___open_grid}"
                       MouseEnter="BTN_OpenDeviceSettings_MouseEnter"
                       MouseLeave="BTN_OpenDeviceSettings_MouseLeave"
                       MouseLeftButtonDown="BTN_OpenDeviceSettings_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                       MouseLeftButtonUp="BTN_OpenDeviceSettings_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                </Rectangle>
```

And it works great. But I want to separate the graphics from the code, and to make this work I manually swap the fill image in my C# code. I have seen code like:

```
<Button Name="btnNext" Padding="15,3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="OnButtonClick">
    <Image Width="90" Height="90">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/resources/a.png" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/resources/b.png" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

So I think that is what I am wanting. But ideally, I am going to have many of these buttons, so can I create something so that I do this:

```
<MyButton>
  <Images idleImage="someimage.png" hoverImage="someOtherImage.png" clickImage="someOtherOtherImage.png" onCLick="some_cSharp_method_to_call" />
</MyButton>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913422/change-button-background-image-on-hover-click-using-a-template

Answer (score 0):

First solution: you can create a control template(or style if you are planning to show only images within a button) for buttons which will declare what images will be used for overlapping/clicking/other operations. This style will be shared by all buttons you want because it will have a designated key.

Second solution: you can subclass button and declare 3 dependency properties for hover/idle/clicked images. Then again you will need some default template(or style if button only displays images) for your subclassed button which will use that dependency properties.

Comment: Sounds great, except I have very little idea how to actually implement that in WPF. I can do pretty much anything in C# but WPF is a strange beast and I am learning on the fly.

I am interested in solution #2 as this seems like it would be useful for if I were to create a WPF-version of a UserControl with a ListBox and some text over it and I want to pass in what the text is (just an example). Do you have any example code or references that helps explain what #2 means?