# Change image background button image and restore old

Tags: wpf, imagebutton

[WPF, XAML]I have 1 button, in present it's background image is image1.png
But now i want when click this button, it's background image change is image2.png, and don't click it's background image is image1.png, (restore old image).
Code :

Comment: If i got this right, then you need to use VisualStateManager for IsPressed, or use trigger for this property.
check in msdn button's original controlTemplate, and you will see what i mean - change visual style on IsPressed.

Comment: Please, before posting question on StackOverflow, put some effort in searching the web for already existing solutions to your problems.

Comment: I can answer this but Bitdefender free antivirus have killed my Visual Studio 2015 RC.

Comment: Ben Cohen, I didn't search it, please give me keyword, i can search  google

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9915060/1136211) may also be helpful.

Comment: why i can't use Style.Triggers, anything i missing ?